# How to trigger a "python action" by clicking on the concerned layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

To make my Qgis action work, at the moment I have to select with the mouse a polygon "then" select the action, then click on the layer on which the action is affected. I get the desired result but it's not practical.
How could I get the desired result just by selecting a polygon in the layer in which the action is affected? (below is my current script)

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('p')[0] 
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Z')[0]
for feature in layer1.getSelectedFeatures(): 
    if feature.geometry().within(layer2.aggregate(aggregate=19,fieldOrExpression='$geometry')[0]):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'parcel ', str({feature["idpar"]}) + ' is IN')      
    else:        
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'parcel ', str({feature["idpar"]}) + ' is OUT')
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the script below for your action:

```py
from qgis.PyQt import QtWidgets

layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Z')[0]
feature = layer1.getFeature([%$id%]) 
if feature.geometry().within(layer2.aggregate(aggregate=19,fieldOrExpression='$geometry')[0]):
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'parcel ', f'{feature["idpar"]} is IN')
else:
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'parcel ', f'{feature["idpar"]}  is OUT')
```

BTW, you only need canvas scope here. Now simply select the layer in the Table of Contents and select the action. Then when you click on any feature in the layer on which the action is set, you will get the message box pop up telling you if the feature is in or out.

Again, please note the use of Python f-string formatting here ;-)

Tested with a couple of polygon layers. For reference, this how my Action dialog is configured (the script is slightly adapted for my own layer/field names:

[image]

The resulting action can be seen in the following short screencast:

[image]